# Finding pairs of nodes at distance 2 in a graph using MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, graph, mapreduce

How to write a Mapper class and Reducer class for a directed graph G=(V,E). Need to compute all pairs of nodes (x,y) such that y is reachable from x in two hops, i.e., there is a node z such that both (x,z) and (z,y) are in E. Here (x,y) may or may not be in E.

The input should be an edge with node IDs separated by a tab, for instance:

```
1 2
0 1
3 2
2 3
4 1
...
```

The output should be a list of node pairs x y connected by a path of length exactly 2, one per line, for instance:

```
1 3
4 2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "two hops" means that there needs to be middle Node between two nodes. For example "z" is the middle node for (x, y) pair.

What you can do is have Node ID to be the Key in your Mapper and Reducer.

This way you will collect all edges that "z" is involved into one collection that is going to be passed into your Reducer.

In reducer you add the code that will try to find all (x, y) pairs that are connected via z.

From your example the reducer will get all edges for:

```
key: 1 - Edges (reducer values): (1, 2), (0, 1) => produces no pair
key: 2 - Edges (reducer values): (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 3) => produces (1, 3) as 2 in the middle
key: 3 - Edges (reducer values): (3, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3) => produces no pair
```